# start date to end date in datepicker ios

Tags: ios, date, datepicker

I implement `date picker` in my demo application. Now i have to buttons named `start date` and `end date`.Suppose user can select start date. Now i want to only show dates in date picker from user selected date in start date. For example If i select todays date as a `start date` then user can't able to select before date that i select as a `start date` in `end date`.Please someone suggest.

This is my code to implement date picker

in viewDidLoad()

```
[_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Method

```
   - (void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    _lblAddLeave.text = strDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties for setting maximum and minimum date on `UIDatePicker`. The dates out of these range will be visible, but the user won't be able to select them.

```
datePicker.maximumDate = yourMaxDate
datePicker.minimumDate = yourMinDate
```